# Salesforce doc, meaning of '-'

Tags: salesforce

I have a doc from my client. I don't understand the below statement.
what is meaning of "-";

```
string lldRecType='-';
```

Answer (score 4):

It is assigning the value `-` to the `string` variable `lldRecType`.  So, when you use the `lldRecType` variable, it will return the value `-`.

Comment: Thanks smith, what would we assume the value for sign '-'; Is it any string or value?

Answer (score 0):

The value of "-" is just literally the hyphen symbol. It doesn't stand for anything or have a special meaning.